# No module named "urllib3" Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, pip

I have worked with Selenium before and everything was fine but suddenly it stopped working. I have tried to reinstall Python, Selenium and updated pip. When I run this simple Python Selenium script :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Chrome('drivers/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
sleep(5)
```

It returns the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jan\Desktop\Python\Selenium\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "C:\Users\Jan\Desktop\Python\Selenium\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Jan\Desktop\Python\Selenium\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 29, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver
  File "C:\Users\Jan\Desktop\Python\Selenium\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .remote_connection import RemoteConnection
  File "C:\Users\Jan\Desktop\Python\Selenium\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 24, in <module>
    import urllib3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'
```

Is there something I am missing?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: using python3 or 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like urllib3 is not installed.

Try typing `pip install urllib3` into terminal.

Another solution may be correctly activating your environment variable. To do this, type `source [env]/bin/activate` into terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Since **Selenium 3.14.0** *Selenium* have *swap out httplib for urllib3*.

But this error message...

```
    import urllib3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'
```

...implies that the **Python**  client was unable to import **urllib3**.

However I suspect the main issue is the usage of an *older version* of `pip` that is installed by your systems *package manager* and can be replaced with a newer version of **pip**.

### Solution

Upgrading **`pip`** to the latest version (atleast v**18.0**) will solve your problem.

```
C:\Users\myUser>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦| 1.3MB 544kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
Successfully installed pip-18.0
```